# POSIX extended regular expressions - search two words on separate lines

Tags: regex, posix-ere

Please, help create a regular expression that looking for the word "aaa" and "llll" in the text (not in one line).

Text example 1 (three lines):

> **aaa** bbbbb ccc
>   jjj pppppppp mmmm
>   fff ggg **llll** www zzzz

Text example 2 (three lines):

> aaa bbbb gggg
>   dddd kkkk
>   mmmm ttttt

In Example 1, the regular expression should be "true".
In Example 2, the regular expression should be "false".

Comment: What's your regex look like so far?

Comment: if you remove the first word "Help", this could become a question in exam, or homework question.

Comment: Now it's "aaa.+llll" (check only one line). How to correct expression to check other lines also?

Comment: Can you post the command that you're using to test your regex? Most POSIX tools don't really support multiline matches anyway . . .

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
This is not a command, the regular expression I need to specify in the application that checks the text for a match. I don't now how the application works, but if you can help with the preparation of expression, I will be grateful.